# CakePHP ZipArchive undedifined method

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I want to type

```
class ZipController extends AppController {

$folder_path = 'c:/Testaufgabe';
$zip_name = 'c:/my_zipped_file.zip'; // to simiou kai to onoma tou arxeiou pou tha apothikeuti                

        public function upload(){
        $za = new ZipArchive();
        $res = $za->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);

        if($res === TRUE){  
            //$za->addFile($folder_path , basename($folder_path ));   // edo gia deuteri parametro theloume to onoma mono tou arxeiou
            $za->addDir($folder_path, basename($folder_path));
            $za->close();
        } 
        else  { 
            echo 'Could not create a zip archive';
        }   }



public function addDir($path, $root){
//   $za->addEmptyDir($root);
    //echo 'ok';
   // $this->addDirDo($path, $root, $za);
}}
```

But when I call `$za->addDir($folder_path, basename($folder_path));`

it says that Call to undefined method ZipArchive::addDir()

I would like to have some help please

I use CAKEPHP V3

Comment: This is _not_ a CakePHP problem!

Comment: My question is how to do it in CAKEPHP I need your help....

Comment: I want to make something like 

Class myzip extends ZipArchive{

}

but I dont know how.... please help its important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a method on a `ZipArchive` object that does not exist. You created the method in the controller, not in the `ZipArchive` class... What about calling the method of the controller instead?

```
    if($res === TRUE){  
        $this->addDir($za, $folder_path, basename($folder_path));
        $za->close();
    }

public function addDir($za, $path, $root){
   $za->addEmptyDir($root);
   echo 'ok';
   $this->addDirDo($path, $root, $za);
}
```